# How to get proper tick labels for a colarbar with discrete logarithmic steps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a scatter plot on which I have colormapped the points using `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm`. This gives me the colour map scale which I desire, but I am not able to make this a discrete colormap.
Here's what I have:

[image: 2D position over time, smooth cmap]

I am aiming for something like this (ignoring the inset plot) :

[image: 2D position over time, segmented cmap]

I am able to use `matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm` with some level of success, but seem to lose the helpful  formatting of the colorbar from `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm`:

[image: 2d Position over time, segmented cmap sort of working]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the text for the colorbar ticks.  Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, LogNorm
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 60)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 60)
c = np.logspace(-4, 1, 60)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc1 = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='viridis', norm=LogNorm())
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(sc1, ax=ax)

bounds = np.power(10.0, np.arange(-4, 2))
ncolors = len(bounds) - 1
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('turbo', ncolors)
norm = BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=ncolors)

sc2 = ax.scatter(x, y + 0 + 0.1, c=c, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc2, ax=ax)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([f'$10^{{{np.log10(b):.0f}}}$' for b in bounds])

plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar with power of 10 ticks]

Comment: This is great thanks. For some reason the tick lables for the colorbar are coming out as a different font to the rest of my plot. Whats the reason for this?

Comment: With the dollar signs, matplotlib uses latex formatting instead of the regular fonts.  Those fonts are a bit different. With standard fonts it's harder to create the proper superscripts.